# Visualforce Error - The dependent picklist requires its controlling field on the page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We've got a custom object called `Cost__c`. We've got a custom VFP for this. I want to add a dependencies between two fields, `Product_Type__c` and `Total_Number_of_Pages__c`. Both fields are on the VFP (see below from VFP). Despite them both being on the VFP, I'm still getting the error "The dependent picklist 'Total Number of Pages' requires its controlling field 'Product Type' to be present on the page". I've checked the permissions on both fields and everything seems to be fine there. I thought that maybe it was because it was in an `apex:ActionRegion` but I tried removing that with no luck.

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Product Type" for="product"/>
     <apex:actionRegion >
       <apex:selectRadio value="{!Cost__c.Product_Type__c}" layout="pageDirection" id="product">
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!productTypeOptions}"/>
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="insideInkPanel,issuesPanel" status="refresh"/>
       </apex:selectRadio>
     </apex:actionRegion>
```

.
.
.
.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Cost__c.Total_Number_of_Pages__c}" id="pages">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="method" status="refresh"/>
</apex:inputField>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need both bound on an `<apex:inputField>`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    <apex:inputField value="{!Cost__c.Product_Type__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Cost__c.Total_Number_of_Pages__c}"/>
```

Refer - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm

Comment: Please add more details to answer, like why it will work?

Comment: apex:inputfield will carry all the properties associated with the field in our case the controlling and dependent field and this is not the case if you use it with selectRadio.